# FFT: Extracted spectrum depends on number of points sampled

Tags: matlab, fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

I have a signal $a(t)$, this is how it looks when I plot it:

[image]

Zoom in
[image]

I am trying to extract the eigenfrequencies of this signal using FFT in MATLAB. I do it like this

```
Y=fft( a(1:3:end) );

Fs = 1/1.5;       % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;         % Sampling period
L = dms(2);       % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;    % Time vector

P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:floor(L/2)+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
plot(f, P1)
```

Now, it turns out that if I use `Y=fft( a )`, I only get frequencies close to 0 when I plot the spectrum:

[image]

If I use `Y=fft( a(1:3:end) )`, then I get frequencies at 0 *and* nonzero frequencies:

[image]

1. Why do these nonzero frequencies not appear when I do the FFT on the full dataset, but only when I sample every 4th point?
2. Is the nonzero frequency *actually* contained in my dataset or is it an artifact?

Comment: you should add the sampling frequency you use and how exactly you're plotting this.

Comment: can you also add a zoomed in plot of your time domain signal? I really don't know what you're looking for in the spectrum at this point

Comment: I added a zoom-in as well. I'm trying to extract the oscillation-frequencies of the signal

Comment: can you zoom in more?

Comment: Zoomed in more. It is clear there are very high-frequency modes and low-frequency modes.

Comment: uh-oh. you undersampled. See my answer's edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use Y=fft( a(1:3:end) ), then I get frequencies at 0 and nonzero frequencies:

Well, yes, but that means you *decimate* your signal by a factor of 3, which on one hand will shift frequencies to $\frac13$ of their original frequency, but also will lead to *aliasing*. In other words: unless you know there's no signal above $f=\frac16f_\text{sample}$, you simply can't do that.

### EDIT (based on zoomed-in plots):

So, hand-counted from your most-zoomed in plot, it seems there's about 5 peaks in 20 samples, which implies a period of 4 samples. 
That is ok by Nyquist's sampling theorem.

Now, if you just look at every third sample, which you do by doing `a(1:3:end)`, then there's only ~1.333 samples per period. Nyquist demands that there's at least 2 samples per period. So, your second attempt aliases the signal from the $\frac15f_\text{sample/2}$ onto a different point in the spectrum, where it actually isn't. You damaged your signal by undersampling; you mustn't do that. It's not very clear to me how the idea to do that happened in the first place, but you should definitely read up on the *Sampling Theorem*.

Comment: I added the sampling frequency etc. to my code in the OP

Comment: Thanks, that is a very useful comment. I will have to read up more on this important topic.